# Trying to understand why Eisenstein series is well defined

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-groups, algebraic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

I am struggling to see why Eisenstein series is well defined, and I would greatly appreciate clarification.

Let 
$$
E(x, \lambda) = \sum_{\delta \in P(\mathbb{Q}) \backslash G(\mathbb{Q}) }
e^{\langle H_P(\delta x), \lambda + \rho_P\rangle},
$$
where $x \in G(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ and $\lambda \in X^*(M)_{\mathbb{Q}}$. I want to understand why $e^{\langle H_P(\delta x), \lambda + \rho_P\rangle}$ is well defined with $\delta \in P(\mathbb{Q}) \backslash G(\mathbb{Q})$.

$H_P: G(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}) \rightarrow \mathfrak{a}_M$ is defined by 
sending $nmk \mapsto H_M(m)$.
$nmk$ is from the Iwasawa decomposition of $G(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ and 
$\langle H_M(m), \lambda\rangle = \log \lvert\lambda(m)\rvert$. I am struggling to see how this is well defined on $P(\mathbb{Q}) \backslash G(\mathbb{Q})$.

PS. Here $G$ is a connected reductive group defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, $P$ is a parabolic subgroup, and $P=MN$ is a Levi decomposition.

Comment: $\mid \lambda (m )\mid$ is the adelic modulus. Hence , for a global $rational$ element $p$ of $P$ , the product formula says that $\mid \lambda (pm)\mid =\mid \lambda (m)\mid$. This is the reason $H_P$ is left invariant under elements of $P(\mathbbb Q)$.

Comment: I thought it made sense but turns out I'm actually still a bit confused. $H_P$ is defined by taking the $M$ part, $H_M(m)$. Is it obvious that if we take $pg$, say with $g=nmk$ then the $M$ part of the Iwasawa decomposition of $pg$ is $pm$?

Comment: Ah, yes. $p=um'$ where $u$ is in the unipotent radical and $m'\in M({\mathbb Q})$. Hence $H_P(pm)= H_P(m'm)=\mid \lambda (m'm) \mid =\mid \lambda (m)\mid$.

Comment: I see, thanks again. I just have one last question. There is one thing I'm confused with with this argument. The argument seems to imply that if it happens that $x \in G(\mathbb{Q} ) \subset G(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ , i.e. a global rational point,  then $<H_P(\delta x, \lambda + \rho_P)>$ is always $0$. (because $m$ would now be a rational point hence by the the product formula) so the summand would always be $e^0 = 1$ which seems kind of strange... Am I missing something here?

Comment: No, for a global point, the m part involves the maximal compact, hence m need not be rational.

Comment: Global point $x\in G$ but not in $P$.

Comment: @Venkataramana I have another related question which is not getting any response. If you are interested please take a look. Any input would be appreciated: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332110/question-on-an-application-of-langlands-result-on-the-constant-term-of-eisenste